# Saving HTML form data to local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form section in which people can add their email addresses.

I have a couple of problems:

(1) the page refreshes upon submitting the email address (I understand that this is unavoidable without ajax, or async solutions). It causes the second problem, however,

(2) I am seemingly unable to save these emails as an array and bring them up using `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('EmailsStuff'))`

Part of my JS/Jquery

```
var total = [];
                $(document).on("click", ":submit", function(e) {
                    var stuff = ($($email).val())
                    total = [JSON.stringify(stuff)];

                    localStorage.setItem('EmailsStuff', JSON.stringify(total));
            });
```

and html:

```
<form class="newsletter">

        <input type="email" value="" placeholder="Join Update List Here" class ="newsletter-email" />
        <input type="submit" value="Thanks!" class="newsletter-email" id="fast"/>
    </form>
```

It works if I sample:

```
localStorage.setItem('sample',JSON.stringify(["bob", "susan", "rafiki"]);
```

and consequently read it as

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sample'));
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question from the fragmentary code quoted, but why are you double `stringify`'ing your data when storing it? (And note that the outer parens in `var stuff = ($($email).val())` are completely pointless.)

Comment: Good points. I am really looking for a way to go from a form element to the page refresh to still having an array, such as [example@bla.com, example451@bla.com, etc.]. Conceptually and practically, I am having difficulty framing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the selector for your email input is wrong, try changing it to:

```
var stuff = $('#email').val();
```

And give your input an id:

```
<input id="email" type="email" value="" placeholder="Join Update List Here" class ="newsletter-email" />
```

See this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m8w1uaso/

**Edit:**
If you want to persist all previously entered email addresses and add to this array each time the form is submitted you could do something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ":submit", function(e) {
  var stuff = ($('#email').val());
    // Load emails
  var emails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('EmailsStuff'));
  if (emails) {
    // If the item exists in local storage push the new email address to the array and and save
    emails.push(stuff);
    localStorage.setItem('EmailsStuff', JSON.stringify(emails));
  } else {
    // If the item doesn't exist in local storage set the item to a new array containing new email address
    localStorage.setItem('EmailsStuff', JSON.stringify([stuff]));
  }
});

$(document).on("click", "#loadEmail", function(e) {
  alert(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('EmailsStuff')));
});
```

See this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v9c6xnmh/

Comment: This seems to be great at displaying the values, but it doesn't seem to hold them in an array. I am looking ideally for enter the email (example@example.com) page refreshes (example2@example.com). `console.log(arr)` which holds both example and example2s' emails.

Comment: Fulfills my requirements!

Answer (score 1):

you can prevent the form submit till you save the email array on local storage and then fire the submit.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

there are a few ways to prevent the form submit like

```
<form onsubmit="return myfunc()"... or <form onsubmit="return false"
```

in myFunc you must return false at the end. You can use preventDefault too.

Comment: I think I understand that part, but how exactly do I save to an array if the value resets after the page anyways?

Comment: you save before page gets reload. You prevent the submit, save your emails and then fire the submit.